# SQL Azure login failed

Tags: azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to my database stored in my SQL Azure platform. My ASP.NET app connects to the db properly, but the SQL Management Studio not.

I've added my current IP to the Azure firewal'ls rules list (http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/change-firewall-rule-for-sql-management-studio-connection-to-sql-azure/)

Then, basing on the data from the connection string I pass the server name (tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net) , the username (xxx@yyy)and the password. I'm still getting the error

**Login failed for user 'xxxx'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'xxxxx'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)**

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- You shouldn't need to put "tcp:" before the server name.  Simply yourserver.database.windows.net should work.
- Just the username should work (no need for username@server).
- Are you using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2?
- Could a firewall be blocking port 1433?

When you say your ASP.NET app connects to SQL Azure, is the app running locally or as a web role within a Windows Azure data center?

Comment: I've turned off my Windows Firewall. Also, I did what You suggest. I use the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64) Enterprise Edition

Comment: You need the R2 version of SSMS. I think you have the RTM version